# How can I create a control which is a square and it contains 4 squares inside?

Tags: html, postback

I have a need to create a control which is a square and it contains 4 squares inside. If user clicks on a child square, its background-color will be changed (its background-color has 2 states - WHITE and BLUE) and this state will be updated into Database immediately.
This control will be used in GridView.

I don't know how to create this control so I need your help for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like a cube but if you have only blue and white as chpoice you can not make the fourth side visible.. Either you have to go different color for the sides or play with the transparency of the sides or make the cube rotation possibe.

If uou are using different colors you can place adj shapes lije this
http://www.anopticalillusion.com/2012/03/necker-cube/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Face_colored_cube.png for solid appearance where user will be able to turn it.

Create a user control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vidhya, sorry because my explanation is not clear enough. I don't need a cube here. It's just one dimension square which contains 4 children squares inside and user can interact with these children squares by clicking on them to change its status (It has only 2 states, they are 0 and 1 which displayed by the colors)